# Keep a PubNub subscriber alive as a service (Python SDK)

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pubnub

I feel *so* dumb.

I am publishing messages to PubNub from GPS/Bluetooth nodes. This is working fine.

I need to subscribe to the PubNub channel and import messages into a database 24/7 (Django-based PostgreSQL). I use the database to plot node positions, add keys, sign up users, etc...

**Problem**: This Python script dies after `execute()`. I need it to stay alive forever.

```
# Set up the client params
pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'sub-23948570947502475057205702354702547'
pnconfig.ssl = True

# Connect to PubNub and subscribe to a channel
pubnub = PubNub(config=pnconfig)
pubnub.add_listener(NodeSubscribeCallback())
pubnub.subscribe().channels('node_raw').execute()
```

**Question**: How can I run a subscription to a PubNub channel as a service? In other words, how can I get Python to keep my script running?

**I Tried**:

- Several separate classes to run `PubNub` based on `threading.Thread`
- `while True: time.sleep(10)` after `execute()`
- Hours of Googling
- `signal.pause()` at the end of my script

Comment: Hi there yes you can do this will provide a working example shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a time consuming problem, and I'm not sure of the exact cause. I followed @Stephen Blum 's answer in my initial question/problem, but perhaps I am missing something.

**I made an error of omission** in my initial question: note that I'm creating this subscription inside a `threading.Thread`. I think that's relevant.

Here is how I fixed the problem:

---

The key here was the `signal.pause()` at the end of the `run()` method.

I think it keeps the thread from dying - but I would have expected that with my `NodeSubscribeCallback` (as shown in Stephen's answer).

[image: PubNub Keep Alive Python]

Comment: @StephenBlum I feel like a real "developer" would know what to do, then do it. I am more of a chicken, pecking around fruitlessly until I find the bugs.

Answer (score 3):

## Keep a PubNub subscriber alive as a service (Python SDK)

You can use the Database Sync approach.  Your code is nearly finished.  Just need a few more bits and bobs.  Here is the code you need to accomplish your goal.

```py
import pubnub

from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub          import PubNub, SubscribeListener

class DatabaseSync(SubscribeListener):
    def message( self, pubnub, data ):
        print( "Saving to Database: ", data.message )

pnconfig               = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'demo' ## Only Need SubKey
pnconfig.ssl           = True   ## Use TLS Socket
pubnub                 = PubNub(pnconfig)

pubnub.add_listener(DatabaseSync())
pubnub.subscribe().channels("node_raw").execute()
```

That is it! Super simple and easy way to get a change log of events sync'ed to your database using Python.  Source materials came from [PubNub Python Documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/api-reference-publish-and-subscribe#subscribe) and also an old gist learning [Python by Example](https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/33722e268b3f12c969d90f3ae40244fe).

[image: Save Data to your Database with Python]

Comment: Hey thanks!! I tried this - actually `NodeSubscribeCallback` is very similar to your `DatabaseSync` class. Of course, instead of `print` it saves the message to the database. A different placement of `signal.pause()` is what ended up being successful for me. You can see code below. Now I am trying to get that script running as an independent process that will survive the interpreter dying.

Comment: Excellent!  If you are using [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) or [upstart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) we can provide some tips.

Comment: I am not using those services - that would have made this easier. The issue is that I need to dynamically manage/track daemon processes from Django, based on streaming data from PubNub... So it means a small amount of complexity for me.